# MySQL simple insert query slow on "query end" step

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, profiling

I'm in the middle of trying to virtualize my percona server 5.5.32-31.0 and am seeing something odd.  On the virtualized box inserts (really all) queries are slow, but it's the "query end" step of the profile that's killing response times.

Let me take a step back, here's my test table:

```
CREATE TABLE `mysql_io_test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `time_diff` char(8) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `data` char(100) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Running this:

```
set profiling = 1;
insert into util.mysql_io_test select 999, '99:99:99', 'ABCDEFGHIJ';
set profiling = 0;
```

I get:

```
starting, 0.000031
checking permissions, 0.000005
Opening tables, 0.000530
System lock, 0.000008
init, 0.000008
optimizing, 0.000002
executing, 0.000095
end, 0.000005
query end, 0.067226
closing tables, 0.000013
freeing items, 0.000039
logging slow query, 0.000002
cleaning up, 0.000005
```

On the unvirtualized box (with an older database: v5.5.27-28.1) I get the more reasonable:

```
starting, 0.000039
checking permissions, 0.000004
Opening tables, 0.000013
System lock, 0.000009
init, 0.000008
optimizing, 0.000002
executing, 0.000038
end, 0.000003
query end, 0.000143
closing tables, 0.000008
freeing items, 0.000018
logging slow query, 0.000001
cleaning up, 0.000002
```

I'm not super familiar with the real significance of each of these steps, but I really have no idea why "query end" would be slow.  The manual (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/general-thread-states.html) doesn't give much more information.  I'll try rolling back to an older version and diging into the code tomorrow, but I thought someone might have seen this before and might be able to shed some light on this mystery for me.

A couple other things that might be useful:

- The VM is running on box that's about as powerful as the old one, both are medium range
- There are 6 other VMs running on the box right now
- This sever has generally been slower than the old one
- A couple of large load tests on the new server have been abysmal, but the most recent one was actually faster than the old server.  So I can't say this 'query end' issue happens all the time; though the configuration has changed since the last large test.

Comment: If 6 hundredths of a second is significantly "slow" in your requirements for a write that's committed to disk, you will need to detail the storage configuration (settings, OS, buffers, hardware) that is in use in each case.  And at that, this question probably belongs on [dba.se] rather than SO.  Frankly, I'm amazed that you care about such a tiny difference: feels like pointless micro-optimisation.  Remember Knuth's maxim "*premature optimisation is the root of all evil*".

Comment: On the old server I could get about 1000 rows inserted per second and on the new one is only doing about 15, which doesn't seem appropriate. I don't think it's an storage configuration issue because straight up hard disk testing with fio yields about the same i/o in the VM as on the unvirtualized box. Mostly it's just the weird step that's throwing me off. If it were sending data or something like that it'd be clearer what it was actually spending time doing.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that runs into this I think I've tracked down the issue a bit.  I had changed the innodb_flush_method from ALL_O_DIRECT on the regular box to O_DIRECT on the VM because mysql was giving this warning:

```
kernel: EXT4-fs (vdb1): Unaligned AIO/DIO on inode 17565314 by mysqld; performance will be poor.
```

Reverting back to ALL_O_DIRECT makes that warning start showing up again - but my performance is 100x better on the "query end" step so I'm going to go with it for now.

I hope this helps anyone else who runs into the same issue.